# Eclipse - Android Project from existing Code does not work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, project

i'm trying to import a folder with an existing project in Eclipse, but it wont't work.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> --> Android Project from existing code --> give folder directory --> Finish

Once i try that, nothing happens. Nothing loads, Eclipse doesn't give me an error output, just nothing. Odd thing is that it just happens like that on one single project. When i try to import other projects, everything works just fine.
I am a 100% certain that my project is not corrupted or anything. I just removed it from the Package Explorer and now it won't work anymore.

Thank for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure you are choosing "Android Application project" and not normal project from the wizard..?

Comment: Are you importing android project or general one?

Comment: Is there a `.Project` file in the Folder?

Comment: @CRUSADER: File -> New -> Other -> Android Project from Existing code, also tried it via File -> Import, that wouldnt work aswell

Comment: @shylendra android project

Comment: @FD_ yes, .Project is in the folder7

Comment: @user3244666 Just delete the ".project" file in your project folder then choose Create Android Project from existing source and try

Comment: @FD_ tried that but didnt delete the file, just cut it out with crtl x

Answer (score 1):

Once try this:

1. File->Import->General->Existing
   Projects into Workspace, Next
2. Select root directory: /path/to/project
3. Projects->Select All
4. UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to working sets"
5. Finish

Comment: not working. tried it with checked and unchecked boxes, with and without the .project-file in the folder, .. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you just removed the Project from Project Explorer, then Eclipse specific files (.project and .classpath) must be still there. Try to import it as existing Eclipse project: *Import* -> *Existing Projects into Workspace*.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. As it turns out, the AndroidManifest.xml contained a duplicated entry (syntax error), causing a parse failure when Eclipse tried to decode it.

After I found the duplicate line, removed it, and re-added the project to my workspace, it showed up in Package Explorer just fine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For my case there was a problem in manifest . Check whether Manifest is proper or not or any other Xml file has any sort of problem .